# Multi select dropdown CakePHP 3 selected issue

Tags: php, cakephp

```
$selected_country = array(1,3);

$this->Form->input('country', [
    'options' => $source_types,
    'label' => 'Country: ',
    'multiple' => true,
    'class' => ' form-control',
    'selected' => $selected_country,
    'type' => 'select'
]);
```

If selected country has only one value then it selects the option but if the selected country has more than one value then it doesn't select any value.

Comment: And whats your question exactly?

Comment: Question is not very clear

Comment: In country list we want to select more than one value in country multi select dropdown then the above code is not working

Comment: Check https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/chained-dropdowns :)

Comment: The link in @mark's comment won't help as it currently does not contain any *multiple* <select>s

Comment: Yes, it does contain multiple selects, two in this case should suffice to show-case how things can work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass more than one value on $selected_country, try it:

```
echo $this->Form->select('rooms', [
    'multiple' => true,
    // options with values 1 and 3 will be selected as default
    'default' => [1, 3]
]);
```

Reference: [CakePHP Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)

Comment: This example was extracted from the official doc.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone this works 
`echo $this->Form->input('venues._ids', ['options' => $venues, 'class'=>'form-control` select4', 'label' => false]); IF you have the database associations set up AND you have it referenced in the controller like so

```
$event = $this->Events->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Venues']
        ]);
```

otherwise adding the 'default' => [1, 2] ids in also works but it has to be first created in the controller and then fed to the view in list form.